# AngularJS - I don`t understand how `factory` works

Tags: angularjs

I got this service where I put all my http request concerning retrieving, deleting and adding a task. The deleting and retrieving of a task works correctly but when I add a task or do an update of an existing task the task change won't show visually. I have to refresh the browser.

I just don't understand how I can't seem to get my adding of a task to work. If anybody can help me out with my code, I would be really grateful.

I made a GIF, where I demonstrate my problem when in this example I update a task
(https://www.dropbox.com/s/qndkfmxde6fos9r/hiI1hBNvSn.gif?dl=0)

Part of my app.js code:

```
zazzleApp.factory('TaskService', function ($http) {
        var TaskService = {};

    TaskService.taskList = [];

    TaskService.addTask = function(pTask){
        var newClickDate = clickDate;
        console.log('LOGGGING NEW CLICK DATE = ', clickDate);

        var newEditId = editId;
        console.log('LOGGGING NEW edit id = ', newEditId);
        var url;

        console.log('edit id = ' , newEditId);

        if (newEditId) {
            url = 'api/task/update/' + newEditId;
        } else {
            url = 'api/task/create';
        }

        console.log("URL URL USA", url, newEditId);

        defaultStart = new Date(newClickDate);
        defaultStart = defaultStart.getFullYear() + "-" + (defaultStart.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + defaultStart.getDate();
        defaultStart += " 00:00:00";

        defaultEnd = new Date(newClickDate).addDays(1);
        defaultEnd = defaultEnd.getFullYear() + "-" + (defaultEnd.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + defaultEnd.getDate();
        defaultEnd += " 00:00:00";

        console.log('LOGGING DEFAULT START AND DEFAULT END ' , defaultStart, defaultEnd);

        pTask.color = $('#containerColorPicker').attr('ng-data-id');

        return $http.post(url, {
            'name': pTask.project_name,
            'project_id': pTask.project_type,
            'location_id': pTask.location,
            'estimate_time': pTask.estimate_time || 2,
            'project_client_name': pTask.project_client_name,
            'url': pTask.url,
            'resource_link': pTask.resource_link,
            'notes': pTask.notes,
            'start_time': pTask.start_time || defaultStart,
            'end_time': pTask.end_time || defaultEnd,
            /*'start_time': defaultStart,
            'end_time': defaultEnd,*/
            'color': pTask.color
        }, {
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "text/plain"
            }
        })
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log(data);
                TaskService.taskList.push(data);//pushing the new task
                console.log("YYYYYYYYYYYYY -------->>>>>", defaultStart, newClickDate, newEditId);
        })
        .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log("Failed to add the task to DB");
        });
    };

    return TaskService;
})

//START CONTROLLER
angular.module('zazzleToolPlannerApp')
    .controller('CalendarCtrl', function ($scope, $mdDialog, $http, $rootScope, $timeout, User, Auth, UserService, TaskService) {
        $scope.isAdmin = Auth.isAdmin;
        $scope.getCurrentUser = Auth.getCurrentUser;

        $scope.activeUser = $scope.getCurrentUser()._id;
        //console.log('????????????  logging active/current user id', $scope.activeUser);

        $scope.newTask = {};
        $scope.newTask.project_name = "";
        $scope.newTask.project_type = "";
        $scope.newTask.location = "";
        $scope.newTask.estimate_time = "";
        $scope.newTask.project_client_name = "";
        $scope.newTask.url = "";
        $scope.newTask.resource_link = "";
        $scope.newTask.notes = "";
        $scope.newTask.color = "";
        //console.log('00000000000 ', $scope.newTask); //empty

        $scope.tasks = TaskService.taskList;

        $scope.addTaskWithService = function () {
            //note that you can process the promise right here (because of the return $http in the service)
            TaskService.addTask($scope.newTask)
                .success(function(data){
                    //here you can process the data or format it or do whatever you want with it
                    console.log("Controller: the task has been added");
                    $scope.tasks = [];// EMPTY THE ARRAY
                    TaskService.getTasks();
                    $scope.updateGridDataAwesome();
                    $scope.updateGridData();

                    //console.log('Taskservice Controller ', $scope.updateGridDataAwesome);
                })
                .error(function(data){
                    //something went wrong
                    console.log("Controller: error in adding task");
                });         
        }

});
//END CONTROLLER
```

Comment: If you name your **service** Task**Service**, why is it a factory and not a service?

Comment: What does your TaskService.getTasks() do? Is it async? And what about $scope.updateGridDataAwesome() and $scope.updateGridData()?

Comment: Where do clickDate and and editId come from in your code?

Comment: @LionC: sorry about that its not a service but a factory

Comment: I can see that it is a factory, my point is that it should be a service instead.

Comment: @m.brand: TaskService.getTasks() get all my tasks from the db and $scope.updateGridDataAwesome() is a function in my controller that updates my tile

Comment: @LionC: clickDate and editId are global variables ( i made them because i needed to access them in my controller and factory)

Comment: In general, if you have an update-method in angular that updates your view, you probably did something wrong, as that is what data binding is for

Comment: But shouldn't you be writing the response from getTasks somewhere into your scope, so it'll be show again?*EDIT: now I see it you have a binding to your factory tomas_b answer seems to be correct*

Comment: @LionC:mmm ok how to write a service (i have never written one before)

Comment: GLobals are also a sign that something went wrong in your design. Can you not make them parameters of the function? Or injectables attached to a service if you really need them in so many places? Or a constant/value (also injectable)?

Comment: You don't need a service for that.

Comment: 1. Read [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) 2. Refactor your code (use code-styling guidlines) 3. Make plunker. The main mistake is that you are using 2 success functions, and removing reference of $scope.tasks to TaskService.taskList

Answer (score 0):

In the `succes()` callback of `TaskService.addTask` you're assigning an empty array instance to `$scope.tasks`, thus breaking the reference to `TaskService.taskList`. So calling `TaskService.getTasks()` won't have any effect on the scope variable anymore.

Comment: I see. There might be other issues as well, `TaskService.getTasks()` is an async function I believe, so if the code following that call assumes the data is ready, it should be executed in the success callback.

Comment: the callback in the success function of the factory?

Comment: I meant the success function of the http call `TaskService.getTasks()` is (likely) doing. I suggest following what @evc wrote in his comment.